# How to use a plugin for markdown-it-vue library?

Tags: vue.js, markdown

I'm using [markdown vue](https://github.com/ravenq/markdown-it-vue) which is a plugin for vue. It says it's supposed to have superscript and subscript functionality built in, however when I run the code for a subscript I get something that looks like this

```
  y = x b + e
   i   i     i
```

In order to have this functionality I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it-sub) plugin but I'm having a hardtime figuring out how it's supposed to be registered globally with the `MarkdownItVue` plugin. I tried doing this...

```
import MarkdownItVue from 'markdown-it-vue'
import MarkdownItSub from 'markdown-it-sub'

MarkdownItVue.use(MarkdownItSub)
Vue.use(MarkdownItVue)
```

But this is working out...

I'm happy to change approaches too if there's a simpler fix for `MarkdownItVue`

---

Update

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it-vue@1.1.6/dist/markdown-it-vue.umd.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            {{ msg }}
        </div>
        <markdown-it-vue :content="msg" class="md-body"></markdown-it-vue>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            msg: "$y_i = x_i + \\epsilon_i$"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Still no answer for this? I'm trying to use 'markdown-it-attrs' in combination with this library but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I ended up going with React because it works well but I think the answer provided by @MichaelLevy should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working just fine by default. See the example.

Anyway it seems from the docs that if you need to install additional `markdown-it` plugins, it needs to be done [on component instance](https://github.com/ravenq/markdown-it-vue/tree/ffd24702cf9a9c24d2f7e08029f6fd491d5c05bf#more-plugins)

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      content: "H~2~0 - 29^th^"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it-vue@1.1.6/dist/markdown-it-vue.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it-vue@1.1.6/dist/markdown-it-vue.css">

<div id="app">
 <markdown-it-vue :content="content">
 </markdown-it-vue>
</div>
```

Comment: I made an update, I'm still not seeing it displayed how I'd expect

Comment: I can't use an `import` here on SO in runnable examples so I have to use `<script>` tags to import the libs. But that is not important (and is not something you should do). Point is, the rendering is working as expected (run example = proof) So maybe the problem is in the MD syntax you are using. See mine (`H~2~0 - 29^th^`) and yours. Yours even does not work in online [playground](http://www.aqcoder.com/markdown)

Answer (score 0):

The LaTeX rendering requires the stylesheet from `markdown-it-vue`. Make sure you're including it as a `<link>`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it-vue@1.1.6/dist/markdown-it-vue.css">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      content: "$y_i = x_i + \\epsilon_i$"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it-vue@1.1.6/dist/markdown-it-vue.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it-vue@1.1.6/dist/markdown-it-vue.css">

<div id="app">
  <markdown-it-vue class="md-body" :content="content"></markdown-it-vue>
</div>
```

Or importing the file from `markdown-it-vue/dist/markdown-it-vue.css`:

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/markdown-it-vue-demo-wlatex-gfnz7?file=/src/App.vue:154-204)

Comment: I don't know but output of this seems very similar to output in question (which OP didn't like)

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. However, the line after that example says: `In order to have this functionality, I'm trying to use this plugin`. Maybe he does want it that way, but wasn't seeing it, so he tried that plugin.